# Android - Doing something after waiting a while (very simple)

Tags: android, multithreading, audio

Ok, here's my problem, I get confused with all the kind of threads asyntask handlers wait() runnables workers and I don't know how many other things android has to perform a task "not" immediately or in "real time".

What I want to do is basically stop a sound (I'm using soundmanager) after, say, 3 seconds.  If I use wait (it blocks my UI and also pops a 'not responding' message on the screen). Same thing if I use that same 'wait' within a separate thread (I don't know why, it shouldn't, right?. I mean, that's the whole point of a separate thread) 
Anyways, I'm relatively new in Android so. hope you guys can clear this out for me!.

THanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you point out, Android has some **specialised** classes to deal with this issue in an optimised manner.

A more appropriate method than using a pure `Thread` would be to use Android's `Handler` class to accomplish this.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}, YOUR_DELAY);
```

For longer running operations that you would like to do in the background, you could use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

To implement a countdown situation which has regular "tick" callbacks during the period, one could use the [`CountDownTimer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).

All of these have the advantage that they **execute the important code on the UI thread**. This is important in many cases in Android development.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I-m answering my own question in case anyone else has this problem

```
new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {

        try
        {
            sleep(sharedPref.getInt("alarm_duration", 2000)
                    * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}.start();
```

You need to call .START() not .RUN() - This way your UI won't freeze

Silly mistake :)